# How can I parse through this JSON Response from Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Using a Custom Google Search Engine, I am getting this as a response:

```
// API callback
hndlr({
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
  },
  "queries": {
    "request": [
      {
        "title": "Google Custom Search - flower",
        "totalResults": "13390000000",
        "searchTerms": "flower",
        "count": 10,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "cx": "b2dd7f92c3e6e7185",
        "searchType": "image"
      }
    ],
    ...
    }

);
```

How can I get to the object in this handlr({})?

Answer (score -1):

JSON parse can be used to get json strings into object.
example:

```
const person = JSON.parse('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

then you can use

```
console.log(person.name) //expected output "John"
```

Comment: this question was specifically talking about the handlr function that encapsulates the JSON. not the JSON itself